# forcefully log out a specific user among all online users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, logout

In my site administrator can view list all other online users.

Administrator can also disable any account from that list.

Everything was going fine so far. But now I decided to log out the user which is being disabled. How can I do a log out operation for a particular user from the above specified online user list?

NOTE: I'm using default membership schema for my SQL Server database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot logout a user from outside of their session. See [Programatically logout an ASP.NET user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098840/139917)  for a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the above link helped me a lot. I added the following code to page_load event and it worked perfect.  
  
`if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
            if (!user.IsApproved)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redorect("Default.aspx");
            }
        } `