# Force another user to refresh their Claims with ASP.NET Identity 2.1.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using `Asp.NET Identity 2.1.0` and I store a list of `Accounts` that a `User` has access to, as Claims. The `ClaimsIdentity` is generated when the `User` signs in:

```
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add Claims concerning Account
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccountList", SerializedListOfAccounts));

    return userIdentity;
}
```

Let's say that an Administrator revokes `User A`'s access to a specific Account. How can I force `User A` to regenerate its `ClaimsIdentity`? Remember that it isn't in the context of `User A`. And I don't want to wait until the cookie has expired (and a new `ClaimsIdentity` is automatically generated.

Is it possible? Isn't there a way to tell the server to regard `User A`'s cookie as invalid and force it to regenerate it?

The reason I want this behaviour is to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that I can put on my controllers that checks the `Claims` to see if a `User` has access or not, to avoid an extra round trip to the database.

Comment: You'd have to log them out, right?  Maybe this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369225/forcefully-log-out-a-specific-user-among-all-online-users

Comment: @BrendanGreen I don't really want to log them out, just force them to regenerate their claims. I could use UpdateSecurityStamp to force them to log in again, but that would be when to token expires anyway.

Comment: you can log them out and log them in again with updated claims.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not store their claims on cookie, but apply them on every request to the identity early in the pipeline. You'll have to hack `Startup.Auth.cs` to do that. I'm doing just that [here](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L45).

And here is the gist you can work with:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = GetMyCookieAuthenticationProvider(),
            // other configurations
        });

        // other usual code
    }



    private static CookieAuthenticationProvider GetMyCookieAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        var cookieAuthenticationProvider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
        cookieAuthenticationProvider.OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
        {
            // execute default cookie validation function
            var cookieValidatorFunc = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                (manager, user) =>
                {
                    var identity = manager.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user);
                    return identity;
                });
            await cookieValidatorFunc.Invoke(context);

            // sanity checks
            if (context.Identity == null || !context.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return;
            }


            // get your claim from your DB or other source
            context.Identity.AddClaims(newClaim);
        };
        return cookieAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

The drawbacks that you need to apply claims on every request and this might be not very performant. But right amount of caching in the right place will help. Also this piece of code is not the easiest place to work, as it is very early in the pipeline and you need to manager yourself `DbContext` and other dependencies.

The upsides are that the claims are applied right away to every user's request and you get immediate change of permissions without having to re-login.