# how to really logout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, logout, login-control

I use LoginControl for login into my website in asp.net, but when for logout use login status or session.Abandon or .sign out ,there's white backspace, my homepage is loaded and its not secure.

Please help me that use realy logout in my project.

Comment: what do u mean by 'not secure' after u have logged out?

Comment: when user logout and click backspase his page is loaded

Comment: u got issue with session and cookies...make sure u clear them out when u logout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically logout an ASP.NET user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098724/programatically-logout-an-asp-net-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that I use in my master page

```
if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
    .....
else Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
```

and codebehind for logout button:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't work if you use the same master page for Login.aspx, it will cause an infinite redirect loop, which is really bad.

Answer (score 9):

use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` as below:

```
protected void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: i try it but when enter backspace my home page is loaded

Answer (score 3):

Use `Session.Clear()` like this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None worked for me but this does.

```
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Answer (score 2):

The home webpage is loading from the browser cache, use the below metadata tags to force the browser to clear cache after exiting the page

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="proxy-revalidate" />
```